# IE11 @media with width

Tags: css, media-queries

For IE11 I'm using the following @media query:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active){}
```

Which works fine.

But now I want to also have 3 different ones for mobile, tablet and desktop.  I've tried the following:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active), only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    max-width: 83%;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active), only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    max-width: 90%;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active), only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

But its always landing on the last one with a max-width of 100%.  I've tried putting the width before the -ms-high-contrast but it seems to have the same effect.  Any tips on fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you're looking for something more like;

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), 
                  (-ms-high-contrast: none) 
              and (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), 
                  (-ms-high-contrast: none) 
              and (min-width: 576px) 
              and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), 
                  (-ms-high-contrast: none) 
              and (min-width: 768px)
              and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), 
                  (-ms-high-contrast: none) 
              and (min-width: 992px)
              and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), 
                  (-ms-high-contrast: none) 
              and (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```